# I am not getting Output for this PHP Program

Tags: php, pear, nmap

I am not getting Output though i include all the files

```
<?php

    /**
     * Scan network to retrieve hosts and services information.
     */

    require_once 'C:/xampp/php/pear/Net/Nmap.php';

    //Define the target to scan
    $target = array('127.0.0.1','localhost');

    $options = array('nmap_binary' => 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Nmap');

    try {
        $nmap = new Net_Nmap($options);

        //Enable nmap options
        $nmap_options = array('os_detection' => true,
                              'service_info' => true,
                              'port_ranges' => 'U:53,111,137,T:21-25,80,139,8080',//to scan only specified ports
                              );

        $nmap->enableOptions($nmap_options);

        //Scan target
        $res = $nmap->scan($target);

        //Get failed hosts
        $failed_to_resolve = $nmap->getFailedToResolveHosts();

        if (count($failed_to_resolve) > 0) {
            echo 'Failed to resolve given hostname/IP: ' .
                 implode (', ', $failed_to_resolve) .
                 "\n";
        }

        //Parse XML Output to retrieve Hosts Object
        $hosts = $nmap->parseXMLOutput();

        //Print results
        foreach ($hosts as $key => $host) {
            echo 'Hostname: ' . $host->getHostname() . "\n";
            echo 'Address: ' . $host->getAddress() . "\n";
            echo 'OS: ' . $host->getOS() . "\n";
            echo 'Status: ' . $host->getStatus . "\n";
            $services = $host->getServices();
            echo 'Number of discovered services: ' . count($services) . "\n";
            foreach ($services as $key => $service) {
                echo "\n";
                echo 'Service Name: ' . $service->name . "\n";
                echo 'Port: ' . $service->port . "\n";
                echo 'Protocol: ' . $service->protocol . "\n";
                echo 'Product information: ' . $service->product . "\n";
                echo 'Product version: ' . $service->version . "\n";
                echo 'Product additional info: ' . $service->extrainfo . "\n";
            }
        }
    } catch (Net_Nmap_Exception $ne) {
        echo $ne->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: add these lines `error_reporting(-1);` in start of `<?php` and tell what error you got it

Answer (score 0):

if your program do not have any output, it means you have syntax error, fatal error or segment error.

change php.ini setting, enable, dispaly_errors, and error_reporting with E_ALL
usually, this is enough. you can see the error message and fix the bug.

if there still not error message, try create a simple file, only show phpinfo().
if this is ok, usually, you do not have start up error, if not, enable display_startup_errors in php.ini

if you still have no error, check your apache or nginx configure, you probably config the site wrong.

if you still have no error, congratulation! you got segment error.
use gdb to find the reason.